# RavenDB fast substring search

Tags: c#, substring, ravendb

I have perhaps trillions of string sequences. I'm looking for a fast substring search.

I've created an index. When I am trying to get some results( `x => x.StartWith`), it takes about 2 sec on a 3 million object database.

How much time it might take on 500 million objects?

Is it possible to have RavenDB search faster?

```
 store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex("KeyPhraseInfoByWord", new Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexDefinitionBuilder<KeyPhraseInfo>
   {
    Map = wordStats => from keyPhraseInfo in keyPhraseInfoCollection 
                   select new { keyPhraseInfo.Key },
    Analyzers =
        {
            { x => x.Key, "SimpleAnalyzer"}
        }
    });
```

Comment: "I have perhaps trillions of string sequences." I've told you a million times about exaggerating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nier0,
You can do really fast NGram search using RavenDB, yes.
See: https://gist.github.com/1669767

Comment: You won't get any better of an answer than from RavenDB's author!

Comment: There is [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12510321/968003) with examples, explanation, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Ayende's excellent NGram analyzer seems to be made for an older version of Lucene than RavenDB uses now, so I made an updated version of it for confused people like me. See: http://pastebin.com/a78XzGDk. All credit goes to Ayende for this one.

To use it, put it in a library, build it and drop it into the Analyzers-folder under Server in the RavenDB directory. Then create an index like this:

```
public class PostByNameIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Posts>
{
    public PostByNameIndex()
    {
        Map = posts => posts.Select(x => new {x.Name});
        Analyze(x => x.Name, typeof(NGramAnalyzer).AssemblyQualifiedName);
     }
}
```

But as I said, all credit and thanks to Ayende for creating this.